# News Feed Issue On A SimpleXML PHP Page

Tags: php, xml, rss

Can someone tell me why this code is not drawing titles and links from the XML RSS feed from the news website?

I am using the SimpleXML PHP extension to do it.

Here's the code.

```
<?php
   $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://feeds.feedburner.com/ndtvnews-latest?format=xml');
   $tle = [];
   $lnk = [];
foreach($xml -> channel -> item as $node)  {
foreach($node -> title as $node) {
  array_push($tle, $node);
  }
 }
foreach($xml -> channel -> item as $node)  {
foreach($node -> link as $node) {
  array_push($lnk, $node);
  }
 }
?>
```

And in the html body tag, I am including...

```
<div id="list">
 <?php
for ($c = 0; $c < count($tle); $c++) {
   echo '<h2>' . $tle[$c] . '</h2> ';
   echo '<a href="' . $lnk[$c]  . '">' . $lnk[$c]. '</a>';
  }
 ?>
</div>
```

What's odd is, it is throwing two different errors, one on my local host page and one on the server hosted domain page.

On the local host, it says "Object not found" - 404 error.

On the other one, it says "Syntax error on line 3, unexpected '[' found"

How is that possible? Please enlighten me.

Comment: *On the other one, it says "Syntax error on line 3, unexpected '[' found"* - php version before 5.4

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes, found out that PHP was not updated :)